If a kickoff player stops the ball on the one yard line, but only after stepping in the end zone first, where is the ball placed?
In the Jets vs. Broncos game on 2024-09-29, the Broncos stopped the ball on the one yard line, but only after stepping in the end zone. Where is the ball placed?
The ball was then placed on the 1 yard line where the kickoff player stopped the ball, even though he had stepped in the end zone first and then came back to stop ('catch') the ball. I didn't think this was permitted...shouldn't the ball have been placed at the default location as if it had gone into the end zone?

Could you be precise about which play this was? From the ESPN play-by-play, the only drive I see starting at the 1 yard line is the Jets 2nd drive of the game, but that is a) a punt, not a kickoff and b) the Jets received the ball.

I don't have video of this, but presume from the description that rather than a "kickoff", this was a "punt".
While members of the kicking team may not go out-of-bounds and then become the first player to touch the ball (Rule 9, section 2, article 3), there is no such prohibition about a player entering and then leaving the end zone.
The rule is that the player may not be touching the end zone while recovering the kick.
Rule 9, Section 3, Article 2:

Item 3. Touchback. If a player of the kicking team illegally catches
or recovers a scrimmage kick, other than a field goal attempt from
beyond the 20-yard line, and touches the goal line with any part of
his body while in possession of the ball, the ball is dead, and the
result of the play is a touchback. [...]

Also from Rule 9, Section 2, Article 2, Note 3:

(3) If a player of the kicking team touches the goal line with any part of his body while touching the ball, the ball is dead, and
the result of the play is a touchback.

It sounds like the Broncos player had fully exited the end zone, so this becomes a normal punt touching and not a touchback.
